# MvcSiteMapProvider No Separetor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, mvcsitemapprovider

I don't want the MvcSiteMapProvider to display the "`>`" separtor betweent the breadcrumbs.

Example: `Home > Contact`
What I want: `Home Contact` (a separetor between the breadcrumbs is added with CSS).

I dodn't found any property called "separetor" to set this in the docu (https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MvcSiteMapProvider` uses [templated HTML helpers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MSUbLMD_fmw). You can edit the templates any way you want to change the output HTML to meet your needs (including the separator character).

For the `SiteMapPath`, simply edit the template at `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/SiteMapPathHelperModel.cshtml` as follows.

### Default

```
@model MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models.SiteMapPathHelperModel
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@using System.Linq
@using MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models

@foreach (var node in Model) { 
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => node);

    if (node != Model.Last()) {
        <text> &gt; </text>
    }
}
```

### Edit

```
@model MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models.SiteMapPathHelperModel
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@using System.Linq
@using MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models

@foreach (var node in Model) { 
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => node);

    if (node != Model.Last()) {
        <text> </text>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has a separator for this. `<span class="divider">`

Check out this link.

https://joeylicc.wordpress.com/2013/07/08/asp-net-mvc-sitemappath-using-site-map-provider-bootstrap-breadcrumbs/